# Merged branches locally, now how do I get GitHub to show that as a pull request?

Tags: git, github, merge

So I have two branches which I merged locally and thus created a commit. I then pushed the unified branch to my remote where the two branches existed. I'm guessing this is not how it is done since Github doesn't reflect the merge, it simply shows a commit on branch A with the merge message. But it still shows both separate branches.

When I try to merge both branches on Github as a pull-request, there is nothing to merge since both branches are now the same.

Can someone please explain how to do this for future reference?

Answer (score 0):

it simply shows a commit on branch A with the merge message. But it still shows both separate branches.

That is expected: your merge commit should show two parents, which means the second branch is still accessible from the merge commit, while your "unified branch" lives on.

Merging does not mean deleting the second branch.